# Save all generation in Game of Life for later access

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique, conways-game-of-life

My **Game of Life** works perfectly. I also have a counter that shows the current generation (for each iteration `generation++`).

Now I want to be able to access and display any generation during the game. The whole game consists of a two-dimensional array (`Cell[][]`). So after each iteration, the respective array must be saved with a unique name.

But how can I save an array multiple times in a loop? I can't add the iteration-number to the array name like `Cell[][] cells+generation = ...` to become `cells0, cells1, cells2...` arrays.

Another idea was, to create a *class generation* and create a new object of this class for each iteration, but even then the problem of the name of the object generation remains (to be able to access the respective object, a unique name is required, e.g. generation13, generation154 ...).

```
public class Generation {
    private Cell[][] cells;

    public Generation(Cell[][] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public Cell[][] getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    public void setCells(Cell[][] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an approach on how to achieve this? I think that with the *class generation* makes the most sense, because this way you can also access (`get`) the constructor (two-dimensional array) for displaying.

Comment: The point is need TWO things: a) for every iteration you have to create a completely NEW matrix ... and B) as outlined in the first answer you got: those **different** matrix objects could be appended to a list for example.

Comment: You are confused here. Why would you give every matrix a separate *compile-time* name but for the cells in the matrix you don't do the same. You don't write `Cell cell0x0, cell0x1, cell0x2, ...;` but you use an array. It's the same with a generation, which is basically just a 3rd dimension.

Comment: The two-dimensional array is of the `Cell[][]` data type and the name should be e.g. generation13, generation14 ..

Answer (score 1):

What about making an `ArrayList<Cell[][]>`? So, If you want to add a new generation, just use

```
arrayListOfCells.add(generation);
```

And then access it with

```
arrayListOfCells.get(index);
```

Comment: Note: that only makes sense when that array (your generation parameter) is a **new** different object.

Comment: Good approach, I'll give it a try, but since I'm already working with two-dimensional arrays, now I have to convert it to a list ...

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  Just add generation number to the `Generation` class.

```
public class Generation {
    private final int generation;

    private Cell[][] cells;

    public Generation(int generation, Cell[][] cells) {
        this.generation = generation;
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public Cell[][] getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    public void setCells(Cell[][] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public int getGeneration() {
        return generation;
    }
}
```